# ¿Puedo usar una licencia GPL en mi proyecto si utilizo una biblioteca MIT?

Tags: licencias

Estoy haciendo un programa en go y me gustaría subirlo a Github con la licencia GPL, pero estoy utilizando un paquete de otra persona el cual está licenciado con MIT. ¿Puedo hacer esto?

Comment: [Según Wikipedia](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licencia_MIT) es posible: *La licencia MIT permite reutilizar software dentro de Software propietario. Por otro lado, la licencia MIT es compatible con muchas licencias copyleft, como la GNU General Public License[1]​ (**software con licencia MIT puede integrarse en software con licencia GPL, pero no al contrario**).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente, lo que se llama *Licencia MIT* puede ser ambiguo, debido a que MIT ha usado varias licencias distintas para sofware.

Convendría que consultes el apartado [**Licencias de software libre compatibles con la GPL**](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#GPLCompatibleLicenses) de `gnu.org`. Allí se indican todas las licencias compatibles con GPL.

En la larga lista de licencias compatibles aparecen dos de la variantes de MIT:

> - **[Licencia de Expat (#Expat)](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/License:Expat)**
>
> Esta es una licencia de software libre laxa, permisiva, sin copyleft,
> compatible con la GPL de GNU. Algunas veces se la llama ambiguamente
> «MIT License».

---

> - **[Licencia X11 (#X11License)](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/License:X11)**
>
> Esta es una licencia de software libre laxa, permisiva, sin copyleft,
> compatible con la GPL de GNU. Versiones más antiguas de XFree86
> utilizaban esta misma licencia, como así también algunas de las
> versiones actuales de XFree86. Las últimas versiones de XFree89 son
> distribuidas bajo la [licencia XFree86 1.1](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#XFree861.1License).
>
> Esta licencia es a veces llamada MIT license, pero este término es
> confuso, ya que MIT ha utilizado varias licencias distintas para
> software.

Si el software del que hablas está bajo cualquiera de estas dos licencias, o cualquier otra listada en el enlace de más arriba, no tendrás problema de poder usar con una licencia GPL.

### Mapa de compatibilidad

En el mapa de compatibilidad publicado en Wikipedia, podemos ver que la licencia *MIT*, (en el mapa sería X11), pertenece al grupo de las licencias permisivas. Eso significa que usar en nuestro programa código bajo esta licencia no tiene prácticamente ninguna restricción.

La línea de flujo muestra que la misma es compatible con **todas las versiones de GPL**.

<sub>[image]A.hawrylyshen at English Wikipedia - [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) or [GFDL](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/fdl.html), via [Wikimedia Commons](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dc/Quick-guide-gplv3-compatibility.svg)</sub>

Comment: Muchas gracias por toda la información y el diagrama.